# Inline css style fill all paths of an SVG image with 2 layers with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have this code to render SVG image with 2 layers:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 175.94 315.65" style="enable-background:new 0 0 175.94 315.65;" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="Layer_1">
    <path class="st0" d="M18.87,132.57c5.5-2.4,10.1-6.46,15.56-8.94c5.93,1.66,11.11,5.28,17.02,7.01c2.66,0.73,5.6-1.75,5.27-4.51
        c-0.89-6.06-2.93-11.91-3.89-17.97c3.87-4.32,8.15-8.29,11.65-12.92c2.13-2.28,0.96-6.65-2.25-7.12
        c-5.91-1.21-12.12-0.48-17.95-1.96c-3.5-4.67-5.59-10.22-8.91-15c-1.61-2.73-6.41-2.77-7.73,0.25c-2.78,5.11-4.1,10.9-7.05,15.92
        c-5.59,2.4-11.92,2.4-17.68,4.34c-2.4,0.74-3.66,3.97-2.44,6.15c3.86,5.26,10.4,8.04,14,13.44c-0.05,6.01-1.73,11.89-1.57,17.9
        C13.08,132.03,16.35,133.61,18.87,132.57z M7.97,96.55c5.1-1.26,10.39-1.74,15.38-3.44c1.78-0.5,2.43-2.4,3.2-3.88
        c1.77-4.04,3.31-8.18,5.21-12.16c2.46,3.85,4.56,7.91,6.92,11.83c0.92,1.41,1.95,3.14,3.85,3.24c5.06,0.73,10.2,0.83,15.28,1.47
        c-3.21,4.07-7,7.64-10.26,11.67c-1.36,1.43-0.77,3.5-0.47,5.21c0.97,4.39,2.16,8.73,3.09,13.14c-4.08-1.6-8.02-3.51-12-5.3
        c-1.86-0.84-4.12-1.53-6.03-0.46c-4.41,2.33-8.47,5.26-12.92,7.5c0.34-5.1,1.15-10.16,1.45-15.26c0.29-2-1.44-3.33-2.67-4.59
        C14.69,102.49,11.04,99.84,7.97,96.55z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M91.31,36.4c-0.28,3.26-0.71,6.5-0.99,9.76c3.01-1.2,5.73-3.46,8.98-3.83c2.91,0.96,5.53,2.62,8.37,3.79
        c-0.35-3.28-0.86-6.53-1.32-9.79c2.23-2.23,4.46-4.48,6.41-6.96c-2.97-0.59-6.01-0.83-8.92-1.64c-2.22-2.39-3.3-5.57-4.94-8.35
        c-1.91,2.64-3.34,5.56-4.7,8.5c-3.1,0.53-6.2,0.97-9.28,1.58C86.77,32.01,89,34.26,91.31,36.4z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
    <path class="st0" d="M131.76,6.63c-4.41-2.49-8.64-6.53-13.79-6.63c-3.51-0.07-3.26,4.66-1.31,6.69
        c11.46,16.14,17.89,35.91,17.57,55.74c-0.11,31.34-16.95,62.09-43.45,78.87c-16.18,10.43-35.6,15.92-54.87,14.88
        c-5.34,0.24-11.48-3.97-15.92-0.97c-1.16,0.78-1.2,3.01,0.04,4.1c2.29,2.42,5.11,4.24,7.8,6.19c-0.06,37.67-0.08,75.34,0.01,113
        c0.06,4.19-2.57,7.7-4.24,11.36c-4.12,0.73-8.31,1.1-12.38,2.07c-0.09,0.36-0.29,1.08-0.38,1.44c2.63,3.25,6.28,5.59,8.65,9.05
        c-0.23,4.44-1.44,8.77-1.54,13.23c4.23-1.58,8.16-3.83,12.08-6.04c4.13,2.01,8.13,4.35,12.5,5.83c-0.34-4.45-1.19-8.83-2.11-13.18
        c3.1-3.45,6.57-6.55,9.5-10.15c-4.38-1.22-8.9-1.75-13.4-2.27c-1.79-3.61-4.57-7.09-4.3-11.34c0.05-36.71-0.03-73.43,0.04-110.14
        c13.71,7.75,29.09,12.61,44.88,13.24c0.09,5.62,0.04,11.23,0.11,16.85c-0.08,2.38,0.32,5.05-1.26,7.07
        c-3.67,5.49-5.56,11.88-8.18,17.88c-5.89,1.57-11.95,2.38-17.8,4.05c-3.11,0.8-3.82,5.35-1.48,7.39c4,4.19,9.07,7.27,12.89,11.66
        c0.36,6.3-1.72,12.49-1.31,18.79c0.23,2.84,4.14,4.25,6.43,2.86c5.2-2.8,10.04-6.25,15.27-9.04c5.47,2.35,10.67,5.38,16.36,7.21
        c2.26,0.79,5.06-0.8,5.49-3.14c0.25-6.63-3.46-12.78-3.39-19.34c3.36-4.62,7.94-8.22,11.32-12.83c1.92-2.2,1-6.45-2.06-7.04
        c-6.02-1.29-12.24-0.91-18.32-1.84c-3.07-5.8-6.85-11.23-9.61-17.17c-0.54-7.72,0.07-15.49-0.29-23.23
        c26.26-0.27,52.18-11.62,69.93-31.01c13.2-14.35,21.7-32.94,23.98-52.3C179.8,62.89,162.27,25.51,131.76,6.63z M86.98,226.42
        c0.83,1.39,2.55,1.47,3.99,1.68c4.65,0.49,9.33,0.76,13.99,1.32c-2.79,3.22-5.67,6.36-8.55,9.49c-1.29,1.53-3.06,3.25-2.55,5.47
        c0.78,5.06,2.33,9.96,3.26,15c-4.81-1.94-9.41-4.4-14.29-6.15c-1.76-0.9-3.45,0.31-4.96,1.1c-3.96,2.3-7.78,4.81-11.75,7.08
        c0.35-5.28,1.44-10.5,1.59-15.79c0.2-1.9-1.47-3.11-2.64-4.3c-3.3-2.95-6.84-5.63-9.83-8.9c5.02-1.43,10.28-1.87,15.24-3.52
        c1.74-0.51,2.35-2.39,3.09-3.85c1.74-4.07,3.37-8.2,5.28-12.2C81.77,217.25,83.92,222.12,86.98,226.42z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now I have a span element with background color and class "check" assigned:

```
<span class="check" style="background-color: #4d1b18">Brown</span>
```

and the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var svg = document.querySelector('span.check');
var layer1 = document.querySelector('#Layer_1');
var matches = layer1.querySelector('path');
matches.style.fill = svg.style.backgroundColor;
</script>
```

You can check the [fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/robb84/2rvzy3xf/)

As you can see, the fill is applied only to the **first path of #layer_1** the second path in same ID as well (there may be even more).
How to inline the style to all path inside the Layer_1 ID ?

Comment: apply the fill to the <g> parent element instead

Comment: @RobertLongson The simple and best approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('span.check');
var layer1 = document.querySelector('#Layer_1');
var matches = layer1.querySelectorAll('path');

matches.forEach(fillColor);

function fillColor(item, index) {
matches[index].style.fill = svg.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 175.94 315.65" style="enable-background:new 0 0 175.94 315.65;" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="Layer_1">
    <path class="st0" d="M18.87,132.57c5.5-2.4,10.1-6.46,15.56-8.94c5.93,1.66,11.11,5.28,17.02,7.01c2.66,0.73,5.6-1.75,5.27-4.51
        c-0.89-6.06-2.93-11.91-3.89-17.97c3.87-4.32,8.15-8.29,11.65-12.92c2.13-2.28,0.96-6.65-2.25-7.12
        c-5.91-1.21-12.12-0.48-17.95-1.96c-3.5-4.67-5.59-10.22-8.91-15c-1.61-2.73-6.41-2.77-7.73,0.25c-2.78,5.11-4.1,10.9-7.05,15.92
        c-5.59,2.4-11.92,2.4-17.68,4.34c-2.4,0.74-3.66,3.97-2.44,6.15c3.86,5.26,10.4,8.04,14,13.44c-0.05,6.01-1.73,11.89-1.57,17.9
        C13.08,132.03,16.35,133.61,18.87,132.57z M7.97,96.55c5.1-1.26,10.39-1.74,15.38-3.44c1.78-0.5,2.43-2.4,3.2-3.88
        c1.77-4.04,3.31-8.18,5.21-12.16c2.46,3.85,4.56,7.91,6.92,11.83c0.92,1.41,1.95,3.14,3.85,3.24c5.06,0.73,10.2,0.83,15.28,1.47
        c-3.21,4.07-7,7.64-10.26,11.67c-1.36,1.43-0.77,3.5-0.47,5.21c0.97,4.39,2.16,8.73,3.09,13.14c-4.08-1.6-8.02-3.51-12-5.3
        c-1.86-0.84-4.12-1.53-6.03-0.46c-4.41,2.33-8.47,5.26-12.92,7.5c0.34-5.1,1.15-10.16,1.45-15.26c0.29-2-1.44-3.33-2.67-4.59
        C14.69,102.49,11.04,99.84,7.97,96.55z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M91.31,36.4c-0.28,3.26-0.71,6.5-0.99,9.76c3.01-1.2,5.73-3.46,8.98-3.83c2.91,0.96,5.53,2.62,8.37,3.79
        c-0.35-3.28-0.86-6.53-1.32-9.79c2.23-2.23,4.46-4.48,6.41-6.96c-2.97-0.59-6.01-0.83-8.92-1.64c-2.22-2.39-3.3-5.57-4.94-8.35
        c-1.91,2.64-3.34,5.56-4.7,8.5c-3.1,0.53-6.2,0.97-9.28,1.58C86.77,32.01,89,34.26,91.31,36.4z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
    <path class="st0" d="M131.76,6.63c-4.41-2.49-8.64-6.53-13.79-6.63c-3.51-0.07-3.26,4.66-1.31,6.69
        c11.46,16.14,17.89,35.91,17.57,55.74c-0.11,31.34-16.95,62.09-43.45,78.87c-16.18,10.43-35.6,15.92-54.87,14.88
        c-5.34,0.24-11.48-3.97-15.92-0.97c-1.16,0.78-1.2,3.01,0.04,4.1c2.29,2.42,5.11,4.24,7.8,6.19c-0.06,37.67-0.08,75.34,0.01,113
        c0.06,4.19-2.57,7.7-4.24,11.36c-4.12,0.73-8.31,1.1-12.38,2.07c-0.09,0.36-0.29,1.08-0.38,1.44c2.63,3.25,6.28,5.59,8.65,9.05
        c-0.23,4.44-1.44,8.77-1.54,13.23c4.23-1.58,8.16-3.83,12.08-6.04c4.13,2.01,8.13,4.35,12.5,5.83c-0.34-4.45-1.19-8.83-2.11-13.18
        c3.1-3.45,6.57-6.55,9.5-10.15c-4.38-1.22-8.9-1.75-13.4-2.27c-1.79-3.61-4.57-7.09-4.3-11.34c0.05-36.71-0.03-73.43,0.04-110.14
        c13.71,7.75,29.09,12.61,44.88,13.24c0.09,5.62,0.04,11.23,0.11,16.85c-0.08,2.38,0.32,5.05-1.26,7.07
        c-3.67,5.49-5.56,11.88-8.18,17.88c-5.89,1.57-11.95,2.38-17.8,4.05c-3.11,0.8-3.82,5.35-1.48,7.39c4,4.19,9.07,7.27,12.89,11.66
        c0.36,6.3-1.72,12.49-1.31,18.79c0.23,2.84,4.14,4.25,6.43,2.86c5.2-2.8,10.04-6.25,15.27-9.04c5.47,2.35,10.67,5.38,16.36,7.21
        c2.26,0.79,5.06-0.8,5.49-3.14c0.25-6.63-3.46-12.78-3.39-19.34c3.36-4.62,7.94-8.22,11.32-12.83c1.92-2.2,1-6.45-2.06-7.04
        c-6.02-1.29-12.24-0.91-18.32-1.84c-3.07-5.8-6.85-11.23-9.61-17.17c-0.54-7.72,0.07-15.49-0.29-23.23
        c26.26-0.27,52.18-11.62,69.93-31.01c13.2-14.35,21.7-32.94,23.98-52.3C179.8,62.89,162.27,25.51,131.76,6.63z M86.98,226.42
        c0.83,1.39,2.55,1.47,3.99,1.68c4.65,0.49,9.33,0.76,13.99,1.32c-2.79,3.22-5.67,6.36-8.55,9.49c-1.29,1.53-3.06,3.25-2.55,5.47
        c0.78,5.06,2.33,9.96,3.26,15c-4.81-1.94-9.41-4.4-14.29-6.15c-1.76-0.9-3.45,0.31-4.96,1.1c-3.96,2.3-7.78,4.81-11.75,7.08
        c0.35-5.28,1.44-10.5,1.59-15.79c0.2-1.9-1.47-3.11-2.64-4.3c-3.3-2.95-6.84-5.63-9.83-8.9c5.02-1.43,10.28-1.87,15.24-3.52
        c1.74-0.51,2.35-2.39,3.09-3.85c1.74-4.07,3.37-8.2,5.28-12.2C81.77,217.25,83.92,222.12,86.98,226.42z"/>
</g>
</svg>
<span class="check" style="background-color: #0f0">Green</span>
```